# Python Error Using qgis2web

Tags: python, qgis2web

I do not know Python, but I am trying to use the qgis2web plugin to create an interactive map. I was following the steps but got this error when following the published steps.

```
WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tabitha/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 337, in previewMap
  preview_file = self.createPreview()
  File "C:/Users/Tabitha/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 300, in createPreview
  dest_folder=utils.tempFolder()).index_file
  File "C:/Users/Tabitha/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletWriter.py", line 101, in write
  folder=dest_folder)
  File "C:/Users/Tabitha/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletWriter.py", line 272, in writeLeaflet
  useVT, useShapes, useOSMB)
  File "C:/Users/Tabitha/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletLayerScripts.py", line 127, in writeVectorLayer
  useShapes, feedback)
  File "C:/Users/Tabitha/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletStyleScripts.py", line 102, in getLayerStyle
  "s": styleCode}
**ValueError: unsupported format character 'B' (0x42) at index 100**
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix or get past this?

Comment: Try to install the newest version of the plugin.

Comment: It should be? I just downloaded it yesterday. I am using the 3.16.16 Hannover long-term version.

Comment: OK, so the next step is checking your map. Does the preview come out?